Загрузка Native файла из ресурса с получением библиотеки внутри файла
Build - .Net Core 8.0 (Console)
Builder - Net Framework 4.7 (Console)
В проект Builder закинул .exe файл build проекта, загружаю его через
byte[] nativeFileBytes = Properties.Resources.BuildTest;

Мне нужно через Native API функции загрузить нативный файл, найти там .dll - она MSIL .Net C# и её загрузить через библиотеку dnlib, отредактировать и сохранить в NativeFile так же чтобы сохранилась и оболочка C/C++ NetCore.
Можно ли такое реализовать?
Вообщем задача такая:

Загрузить Native AOT .Net Core приложение через библиотеку dnlib (но, так как ModuleDefMD.Load грузит только .Net сборки, то это не работает с AOT .Net Core приложениями, остаётся вариант с WinAPI)
Перебрать внутри приложения все .dll и найти ту которая называется как сам файл .exe
Загрузить найденную .dll внутри через dnlib приложение.
Пропатчить .dll и сохранить в том же самом .exe

Вот такая стоит задача, но я не знаю как сделать пока, была мысль что если скомпилирую в Net Core .dll и закину в ресурсы и от туда отредачу, а в dnlib использую NativeWrite module.NativeWrite("BuildTest.exe", options); то на выходе получу нативную оболочку, но нет =) Я наивный хD.
Остаётся только вариант с редактированием через саму оболочку AOT .NetCore лежащий в ресурсах.

Что такое Native? Native AOT? Тогда нет там никакого MSIL. Как собирали - непонятно, как публиковали с какими параметрами - загадка. Вопрос-угадайка. Обфускация вопроса зашкаливает.

@aepot, напишу так, скомплировал (в VS-2022) билд в .Net Core C# на выходе получил .exe и .dll. создал проект C# на Framework и закинул в ресурсы этот .exe. Сам net Core если смотреть изнутри то внутри лежит эта самая .dll - она MSIL код C#. И вот мой вопрос, можно ли из nativeFileBytes  прочитать эту .dll ? Изменить её и сохранить в тот же .exe файле.

Почему бы не закинуть саму dll? Она ведь есть у вас отдельно. И публикация .NET Core приложения производится через publish а не копированием файла из папки Debug. В результате получится один exe без dll. А так, вот же пример https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib - ModuleContext modCtx = ModuleDef.CreateModuleContext(); ModuleDefMD module = ModuleDefMD.Load(nativeFileBytes, modCtx);, редактируйте наздоровье.

@aepot, да, я знаю что она есть отдельно, но суть в другом именно загрузить из NetCore .exe (который как раз через publish сгенерировался) этот файл .exe закинуть в ресурсы и подгрузить, но просто ModuleDefMD не даст загрузить его так как он нативный а не .Net, вот у меня именно этот вопрос интересует, можно ли получить .dll которая вшита в этот .exe файл и уже эту .dll подгрузить через ModuleDefMD

Отредактируйте вопрос, допишите подробности, а то их всё больше и больше. Насколько я знаю, что тот самый exe - это архив, который просто распаковывается при запуске.

@aepot, отредактировал)

Загрузить Native AOT .Net Core приложение через библиотеку dnlib - Native AOT приложение не является .NET сборкой, а является нативно скомпилированным приложением, таким же как C++ сборка например. Я же выше писал, что там нет никаких MSIL и т.д.

@aepot, да, нету, но а как насчёт .dll которая хранится внутри этой Native AOT .exe файла

Ещё раз, Native AOT это не .NET сборка, это полностью скомпилированный нативный код, такой же как C++.

@aepot, а почему тогда .dll легко разбирается в ILSpy, DnSpy и.т.п и видно код, а вот просто нативный код не читает, значит там присутствует IL код который можно редачить. Но собственно хотелось бы по сути чтобы довести дело до конца, можно ли отредактировать через dnlib или asmresolver чтобы на выходе получился такой же файл как из .Net Core. или можно как-то редачить через WinAPI функции ?

Значит это не Native AOT
